# Python can't read mysql csv dump

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I'm trying to read a mysql csv dump but keep getting errors. I saw read some  questions but couldn't get working.

in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM products INTO OUTFILE 'products.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

in Python:

I tried:

```
import csv
with open('products.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in data:
        print ', '.join(row)
```

and got:

> Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open
>   the file in universal-newline mode?

and tried:

```
import csv
with open('products.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
     data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
     for row in data:
         print ', '.join(row)
```

and it worked but it splitted cells containing a newline

and tried:

```
pandas.read_csv('products.csv')
```

and got:

> pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read
>   (pandas/parser.c:7988)()
>
> pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory
>   (pandas/parser.c:8244)()
>
> pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows
>   (pandas/parser.c:8970)()
>
> pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows
>   (pandas/parser.c:8838)()
>
> pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error
>   (pandas/parser.c:22649)()
>
> CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 29 fields in
>   line 25, saw 39

Help anyone?

Comment: Any particular reason not to use mysql's LOAD DATA command?

Comment: I'm trying to export the data from mysql, not insert it

Comment: that makes things clear as mud. Why not directly connect to mysql from python? YOu have already exported from mysql, that's why you have a csv file

Comment: Also pasting some raw text from the csv file (a couple of lines) would be very helpfull.\

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem.  I solved it by also specifying escapechar, e.g.:

```
data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', escapechar='\\')
```